# Start timer on mouseenter and clear on another div entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, timer

I'm building a menu which, on hover of a `unique-link` will open another menu with links (mega menu).

The issue I'm having is that, on hover of said `unique-link` anchor, there's a gap between the anchor and the `div` shown on hover.

To explain, here's a demo:

```js
$(function() {

    var delay=3000, setTimeoutConst;

    $(".unique-link a").on("mouseenter", function() {
     setTimeoutConst = setTimeout(function() {
       $('.showOnHover').addClass('show');
      });

    }).on("mouseleave", function() {
      $('.showOnHover').removeClass('show');
    });
  

});
```

```css
.menu {
  height: 100px;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.menu .menu__options {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.menu .menu__options .item {
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.menu .menu__options .item.a {
  background: green;
}

.menu .menu__options .item.b {
  background: red;
}

.showOnHover{
  display: none;
  height: 200px;
  background:blue;
}

.show{
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu__options">
    <div class="item unique-link a">
      <a href="#">Hover me</a>
    </div>
    <div class="item b">
      <a href="#">Link</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="showOnHover"></div>
```

In the demo you can see, when you hover over the "hover me" link and try to move your mouse onto the blue `showOnHover` div, the `showOnHover` disappears (which is correct, I only want the div to show on that anchor links over).

To work around this, my play was to start a timer once a user overs over the `unique-link` anchor. The way I'm planning this to work is the following:

- User hovers over "hover me" link.
- `showOnHover` div appears (at this point, the user is still hovering over the anchor)
- If a user hovers over the "hover me" link and then moves their mouse onto the grey area (anywhere on `menu__options`), then start the timer a timer. The `showOnHover` div will be visible until this timer reaches 3 seconds.
- If a user hovers over another `a` tag, then reset the timer (and don't show the `showOnHover` div).

Hopefully that all made sense. I've also demo'd my current approach in the snippet above. But cannot get the logic to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i would suggest is to use a debounce method 
[lodash debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce) or maybe [Ben Alman jQuery throttle / debounce](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) whichever you prefer.

So having a debounce method (i'll assume lodash), you can implement it like this:

```
var debouncedSetMenuVisible = _.debounce(function(show) {

  if(show)
    $('.showOnHover').addClass('show');
  else
    $('.showOnHover').removeClass('show');

  }, 500);

 $(".unique-link a, .showOnHover").on("mouseenter", function() {
    debouncedSetMenuVisible(true);
 }).on("mouseleave", function() {
    debouncedSetMenuVisible(false);
 });
```

This will ensure that when multiple events are happening, only the last one will be executed. Also it ensures that this will happen after the delay you specify.

You can use the debounced function only for mouseleave, but i would suggest you use it for mouseenter also as it is better UX (avoid showing mega menu for accidental hovers).

edit (one more thing): showOnHover needs also a mouseenter and a mouseleave event calling the same function (updated code).

Comment: Hi, can't seem to get it to work with your above approach: https://jsfiddle.net/2zkb7Lor/1/

I've also tried the following: https://jsfiddle.net/aovsk123/1/

Comment: you haven't included loadsh library in your fiddle. check this https://jsfiddle.net/p85vf936/